# how to toggle between icons when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to switch between a moon and a sun when the dark mode is enabled or disabled.
Now I have it that I can change once, but after that it stays as a moon.

How do I fix this this?

```
function darkmode() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
   document.getElementById('toggleknop').innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-moon fa-2x" id="maan" style="color:#737eac;"></i>';
}
```

```
<button onclick="darkmode()" id="Knop"> 
  <span id="toggleknop"><i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x" id="zon" style="color:#d8c658;"></i></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Because your code doesn't contain any condition that actually _toggles_ the dark mode icon? Ideally, you would have a boolean stored somewhere which is toggled when you click on the button and later on would update the current icon to the dark mode value.

Comment: You are just doing it once.

Answer (score 2):

## You can change/toggle easily Drak <=> Light only using CSS.

just use '`document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');`' code only for toggle. show icon depend on the parent class. please see the snippet here:

```js
function darkmode() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
}
```

```css
.dark-mode button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.dark-mode .sun-icon,
.moon-icon {
  display: none;
}

.dark-mode .moon-icon {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="darkmode()" id="Knop"> 
 click
 <span class="sun-icon">
    sun <i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x" id="zon" style="color:#d8c658;"></i>
  </span>
   <span class="moon-icon">
    moon <i class="fas fa-moon fa-2x" id="maan" style="color:#737eac;"></i>
  </span>
</button>
```

Maybe it helps to solve your problem.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentTheme = 'dark';

function changeTheme() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');

  if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
     document.getElementById('toggleknop').innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x" id="zon" style="color:#d8c658;"></i>';
     currentTheme = 'sun';
  }else {
     document.getElementById('toggleknop').innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-moon fa-2x" id="maan" style="color:#737eac;"></i>';
     currentTheme = 'dark';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember whether you are in dark mode with a variable stored outside the function:

```
var inDarkMode = false;

function toggleDarkMode() {
  if (inDarkMode) {
    document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    document.getElementById('toggleknop').innerHTML =
      '<i class="fas fa-moon fa-2x" id="maan" style="color:#737eac;"></i>';
    inDarkMode = false;
  } else {
    document.body.classList.add('dark-mode');
    document.getElementById('toggleknop').innerHTML =
      '<i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x" id="zon" style="color:#d8c658;"></i>';
    inDarkMode = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hasClass to check if it contains class.

```
function darkmode() {
 document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
 var toggleknop=  document.getElementById('toggleknop');
if(toggleknop.hasClass('fa-sun')
{
toggleknop.classList.remove('fa-sun');
toggleknop.classList.add('fa-moon');
//Your styling
}
else if(toggleknop.hasClass('fa-moon') {
toggleknop.classList.remove('fa-moon');
toggleknop.classList.add('fa-sun');//Your styling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function darkmode() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
    document.getElementById('toggleknop').innerHTML = document.body.classList.contains('dark-mode') ? '<i class="fas fa-moon fa-2x" id="maan" style="color:#737eac;"></i>' : '<i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x" id="zon" style="color:#d8c658;"></i>';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button onclick="darkmode()" id="Knop"> 
  <span id="toggleknop"><i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x" id="zon" style="color:#d8c658;"></i></span>
</button>
```

```
function darkmode() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
    document.getElementById('toggleknop').innerHTML = document.body.classList.contains('dark-mode') ? '<i class="fas fa-moon fa-2x" id="maan" style="color:#737eac;"></i>' : '<i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x" id="zon" style="color:#d8c658;"></i>';
}
```